# Windows Service Does Not Fire OnStart Event

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have windows service application. But the OnStart event does not fire. Only OnStop event is firing every time I stop the service. What did I miss ?

```
    public partial class Scheduler : ServiceBase
    {
        private Timer timer1 = null;

        public Scheduler()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            timer1 = new Timer();
            timer1.Interval = 5000;
            timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            Library.Log(String.Format("Windows service stopped"));
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Library.Log(String.Format("Scheduler service {0}", DateTime.Now));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OnStart is firing, your timer is not.

You must either do `timer1.Start()` or `timer1.Enabled = true` in OnStart for the timer to start firing.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    Library.Log("Windows service started");
    timer1 = new Timer();
    timer1.Interval = 5000;
    timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
    timer1.Start()
}
```